# Can I change the screen brightness?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

I got a New 3DS XL today and have been playing Super Mario World.  It's great but I find the screen a little dark. Is there any way to brighten it at all?

Comment: I would very much assume it's the same as the New 3DS (which is what I have), where the brightness control is on the home menu settings panel in the top left corner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Nintendo Support](http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/48/~/how-to-adjust-screen-brightness):

> - Select the HOME Menu Settings icon in the upper left corner of the HOME Menu.
>
>   - Nintendo 3DS, Nintendo 3DS XL, and New Nintendo 3DS
>       systems: This icon looks like a wrench, a sun, or a home with a wrench
>       superimposted over it depending on the system menu version.
> - Below "Screen Brightness", tap on the desired brightness level.
> - **If using a New Nintendo 3DS XL**, be sure to turn "Auto-Brightness" to "OFF" or the system will automatically reduce the brightness levels
>     based on environmental conditions.
> - Tap "OK."

Comment: I hate things that have Auto Brightness. That's probably what's getting me. Thanks!